# identify user login session timeout -updated post

Tags: php, session, authentication, logout, session-timeout

> **UPDATED!!**

I've been working on my session for so long and have yet to find solutions to it. Probably because I don't understand my code. I'm still new at PHP language and don't understand session much. It'll be great if someone could guide me along.

Below are my codes to handle session timeout. Apologised for the lengthy post as I want it to be detailed so that someone able to help me with this.

**firstSession.php**

```
<?php
session_start ();
if (! isset ( $_SESSION ["isLoggedIn"] ) || ! ($_SESSION ['isLoggedIn'])) {
    // code for authentication comes here
    // ASSUME USER IS VALID
    $_SESSION ['isLoggedIn'] = true;
    // ///////////////////////////////////////
    $_SESSION ['timeOut'] = 1200;
    $logged = time ();
    $_SESSION ['loggedAt'] = $logged;
    // showLoggedIn ();
} else {
    require 'timeCheck.php';
    $hasSessionExpired = checkIfTimedOut ();
    if ($hasSessionExpired) {
        session_unset ();
        header ( "Location:index.php" );
        exit ();
    } else {
        $_SESSION ['loggedAt'] = time (); // update last accessed time
                                              // showLoggedIn ();
    }
}
?>
```

**check.php**

```
<?php
session_start ();
$stillLoggedIn = timeCheck ();
echo $stillLoggedIn;
function timeCheck() {
    if (! isset ( $_SESSION ['isLoggedIn'] ) || ! ($_SESSION ['isLoggedIn'])) {
        session_unset ();
        return true;
        exit ();
    } else {
        // user is logged in
        require 'timeCheck.php';
        $hasSessionExpired = checkIfTimedOut ();
        if ($hasSessionExpired) {
            session_unset ();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**timeCheck.php**

```
 <?php
    function checkIfTimedOut() {
        $current = time (); // take the current time
        $diff = $current - $_SESSION ['loggedAt'];
        if ($diff > $_SESSION ['timeOut']) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

**header.php**

```
<?php
session_start ();
include ('ajax-helper/config.php');
include_once ('ajax-helper/functions.php');
include ('ajax-helper/php-header.php');

include ('includes/firstSession.php');
?>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
```

**ajax.js**

```
window.onload = init;
var interval;
function init() {
    interval = setInterval(trackLogin, 1000);
}
function trackLogin() {
    var xmlReq = false;
    try {
        xmlReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e2) {
            xmlReq = false;
        }
    }
    if (!xmlReq && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        xmlReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    xmlReq.open('get', 'check.php', true);
    xmlReq.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlReq.send(null);
    xmlReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlReq.readyState == 4 && xmlReq.status == 200) {
            if (xmlReq.responseText == 1) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                alert('You have been logged out. You will now be redirected to home page.');
                document.location.href = "index.php";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**account-edit.php**

```
 <?php
    session_start ();
    if (! isset ( $_SESSION ["loginSuccess"] )) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Login failed!');</script>";
        die ( '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'login-redirect.php\'" />' );
    }

include ('includes/header.php');
include ('includes/header-search.php');
include ('includes/header-nav.php');
include ('includes/header-info.php');
?>
```

From my code above, what I getting is even on pages that do not need user to log in, pop up will appear stating that user will need to log in again, as the session has ended, which actually do not make sense. However, what i want to aim for is it checks whether user is log in or not, if user log in over the session period of time, user will be logged out.

Comment: What is on your  check.php? I assume you understand that session management logic should be in php code - not on the client side.

Comment: i've updated my question to make it detailed. @Alex

Comment: You never call checkIfTimedOut() function in php. What do you expect your php code to do? It will return nothing always.

Comment: my session timeout is working perfectly. what I am in doubt is that i added the session timeout to pages which both login user and non-login user can access. but since i add the session timeout, even when user didn't log in, it will prompt the `You have been logged out. You will now be redirected to home page.` pop out. @Alex

Comment: Actually I am not sure I get it correctly. But as I understand you have to track whether user was or wasn't logged in (I mean authorized).

Comment: it was able to track whether user was able to log in and user will be locked out if user access the page over the period of time. What i was unsure is there a page called news.php. This page do not need user to log in. However, user is also able to access this page if user log in to their acc. Hence, how am i suppose to differenciate the session timeout  for both log in and non-login user?

Comment: I'd suggest you to create a list of secured paths and put his list into config or something. And then just check if requested url is in secured list.

Comment: I'm not so sure how it should be done. So sorry I'm still a beginner. Is there example which you can provide? @Alex

Comment: We could discuss it in a private chat

Comment: if you want, of course

Comment: alrights lets discuss it in a private chat since I still can;t get it right @Alex

Comment: Just ping me in a bounty when you are ready

Comment: apologised for not getting back to you. quite busy completing my projects. I'm still stuck at session timeout. however, i've updated my questions. could you explain to me what this means `if (! isset ( $_SESSION ["isLoggedIn"] ) || ! ($_SESSION ['isLoggedIn']))`? is my session variable used correctly? cos i'm confused with **isLoggedIn** and **loginSuccess** @Alex

Comment: I think you are mistaken in your *if* statement. Just define for yourself when a user might be considered as logged in. Your *if* condition means that if there is no 'isLoggedIn' key in $_SESSION array or there is but it value is false will be executed a code inside statement.

Comment: alright understand on the statement. However, `$_SESSION (loginSuccess)` in account-edit.php actually checks whether user is logged in successfully. hence, it is it similar to isLoggedIn ? @Alex

Comment: Yes, it seems to mean the same. Looks like there is no need to set loginSuccess key. You either set isLoggedIn or not. And to check whether user is authenticated you have to check only one key - isLoggedIn. You can do that with one single if: if(!empty($_SESSION['isLoggedIn'])).

Comment: Do you have any simple tutorial on session timeout checks login user that I can refer to? I would like to code session timeout from start as I feel like the example i added above, is wrong that I'm still stuck @Alex

Comment: We could have a call or chat in skype or here in live chat if you'd like. It's a bit difficult to communicate like this - with long pauses.

Comment: True.. But i not sure why i can't send "Let us _continue this discussion in chat._" @Alex