# How to avoid the session timeout in non-login situation php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I have set 2 min for session timeout and if it occurred the page
will redirect to a session timeout page.

However, I have some pages that could be browsed without login.
In these pages, if I leave it more than 2 min, pop out will appear asking user to log in again.  User will go back to click it and it will redirect to session timeout page.

Could anyone teach me, how to get rid of this such that the pages be browsed without login should not occur session time?

**ajax.js**

```
window.onload = init;
var interval;
function init() {
    interval = setInterval(trackLogin, 1000);
}
function trackLogin() {
    var xmlReq = false;
    try {
        xmlReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e2) {
            xmlReq = false;
        }
    }
    if (!xmlReq && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        xmlReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    xmlReq.open('get', 'check.php', true);
    xmlReq.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlReq.send(null);
    xmlReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlReq.readyState == 4 && xmlReq.status == 200) {
            if (xmlReq.responseText == 1) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                alert('You have been logged out. You will now be redirected to home page.');
                document.location.href = "index.php";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**firstSession**

```
<?php
// session_start ();
if (! isset ( $_SESSION ["isLoggedIn"] ) || ! ($_SESSION ['isLoggedIn'])) {
    // code for authentication comes here
    // ASSUME USER IS VALID
    $_SESSION ['isLoggedIn'] = true;

    $_SESSION ['timeOut'] = 120;
    $logged = time ();
    $_SESSION ['loggedAt'] = $logged;
    // showLoggedIn ();
} else {
    require 'timeCheck.php';
    $hasSessionExpired = checkIfTimedOut ();
    if ($hasSessionExpired) {
        session_unset ();
        header ( "Location:index.php" );
        exit ();
    } else {
        $_SESSION ['loggedAt'] = time (); 
    }
}
?>
```

**footer.php**

```
<?php include ('includes/firstSession.php'); ?>
<footer class="main">
<div class="wrapper container">
    <div class="copyright">All Rights Reserved
    </div>

    <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png"></div>

</footer>
</div>
```

*draft ajax.js*

```
window.onload = init;
var interval;
function init() {
    interval = setInterval(trackLogin, 1000);
}
function trackLogin() {
    var xmlReq = false;
    try {
        xmlReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e2) {
            xmlReq = false;
        }
    }
    if (!xmlReq && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        xmlReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    xmlReq.open('get', 'check.php', true);
    xmlReq.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlReq.send(null);
    xmlReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlReq.readyState == 4 && xmlReq.status == 200) {
            return json_encode(array(
                    'role' => $_SESSION['role'], //assuming something like guest/logged-in
                    'user_id'   => $_SESSION['user_id']
                ));
            var obj = xmlReq.responseText;
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(obj);
            //now we can make a comparison against our keys 'role' and 'user_id'

            if(jsonObj['role'] == 'guest'){
                //guest role, do something here
            } else if (jsonObj['role'] == 'logged-in') {
                alert('You have been logged out. You will now be redirected to home page.');
                document.location.href = "index.php";
                //do something else for logged in users
            }
```

Comment: you can simply destroy session...

Comment: I can't because I have this pages which both user and non-login user can access to it. how should i go about it? @raveenanigam

Answer (score 1):

I think since you have a session that is persistent whether logged in or not, you need to base your action on the username (however that is set). See if this is what you are trying to do. I have notated for clarity:

**myfunctions.php**

```
<?php
// return a session set on not set OR false if set
function is_loggedin()
    {
        return (!empty($_SESSION["isLoggedIn"]));
    }
// Check if username is set (not sure how your usernames are stored in your session
// but that is what you want to check here
function user_set()
    {
        return (!empty($_SESSION["username"]));
    }
// Do your set time function
function set_time_out($timeout = 120)
    {
        $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] =   true;
        $_SESSION['timeOut']    =   (is_numeric($timeout))? $timeout : 120;
        $_SESSION['loggedAt']   =   time();
    }

function process_timeout($supRed = false)
    {
        // If a user has NOT already been poking around your site
        if(!is_loggedin()) {
                // Set the timeout
                set_time_out();
                return 0;
            }
        else {
                // If a navigating user is logged in
                if(user_set())  {
                        // Check for expire time
                        require('timeCheck.php');
                        // If they have been timed out
                        if(checkIfTimedOut()) {
                                if(!$supRed) {
                                        // destroy the session and forward to login (or wherever)
                                        session_destroy();
                                        header("Location:index.php" );
                                        exit();
                                    }

                                return 1;
                            }
                    }
                // Set the logged time by default
                $_SESSION['loggedAt']   =   time(); 
            }

        return 0;
    }
```

**header.php**

```
<?php
include_once("includes/firstSession.php");
include_once("includes/myfunctions.php");
process_timeout();
?><!DOCTYPE html>
...etc
```

**check.php**

```
<?php
include_once("includes/firstSession.php");
include_once("includes/myfunctions.php");
echo process_timeout(true);
```

---

**EDIT:**

This is the entire script, both js and php.

```
// return a session set on not set OR false if set
function is_loggedin()
    {
        return (!empty($_SESSION["isLoggedIn"]));
    }
// Check if username is set (not sure how your usernames are stored in your session
// but that is what you want to check here
function user_set()
    {
        return (!empty($_SESSION["username"]));
    }
// Do your set time function
function set_time_out($timeout = 120)
    {
        $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] =   true;
        $_SESSION['timeOut']    =   (is_numeric($timeout))? $timeout : 120;
        $_SESSION['loggedAt']   =   time();
    }

function checkIfTimedOut()
    {
        if(!empty($_SESSION['loggedAt'])) {
                $active =   ($_SESSION['loggedAt'] + strtotime("120 seconds"));
                $now    =   time();
                return (($active - $now) > 0);
            }

        return true;
    }

function process_timeout($supRed = false)
    {
        // If a user has NOT already been poking around your site
        if(!is_loggedin()) {
                // Set the timeout
                set_time_out();
                return 0;
            }
        else {
                // If a navigating user is logged in
                if(user_set())  {
                        // Check for expire time
                        // If they have been timed out
                        if(checkIfTimedOut()) {
                                // destroy the session
                                session_destroy();
                                if(!$supRed) {
                                         // Forward to login (or wherever)
                                        header("Location:index.php" );
                                        exit();
                                    }
                                return 1;
                            }
                    }
                // Set the logged time by default
                $_SESSION['loggedAt']   =   time(); 
            }

        return 0;
    }
```

**check.php:**

```
// Include the functions here
if(!empty($_POST['getPost'])) {
    echo json_encode(array("redirect"=>process_timeout(true),"sess"=>$_SESSION));
    exit;   
}
```

**CALLING PAGE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
function init()
    {
        interval = setInterval(trackLogin, 2000);
    }

function trackLogin()
    {
        $.ajax({
                url: '/check.php',
                data: { getPost: true },
                type: 'post',
                success: function(response) {
                        var instr   =   JSON.parse(response);
                        console.log(response);

                        if(instr.redirect == 1) {
                                clearInterval(interval);
                                alert('You have been logged out. You will now be redirected to home page.');
                                document.location.href = "index.php";
                            }
                    }
        });
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    var interval;
    init();
});
</script>
```

---

> EDITED

[image]

Comment: thanks! but what if I've added the session timeout ajax at footer and added to all pages, which some pages both users(non-login and login user)can access to it; non-login user wants to access to the page and experience the pop up which prompt user to login redirect even when user didn't log in to their account? how should i differenciate the session timeout in the page?

Comment: Its the same thing. Your ajax should get a response back from the checker to reload or not, so `check.php` needs to have the same logic but instead of doing `header()` redirects, it should echo `0` for no redirect and `1` for redirect so your ajax knows what to do.

Comment: i don't get how i should code from what you've explained :-( @Rasclatt

Comment: Ok hold on. I will revise. One thing to mention, this session logic should come before the page displays to browser, not way down at the bottom of the page

Comment: see my revision, perhaps it will give you a better idea of what I am recommending

Comment: i somewhat got the idea idea. Do you think i should call it in footer.php? but if it's in footer.php, it will be all the way at the bottom @Rasclatt

Comment: You should not call any of this in the footer (php). That is why I added it to the `header.php` (presuming that you have one, of course).

Comment: i tried to follow your method, however, it has no difference. It will still call the pop up asking user will be redirected to homepage, even when user have yet to log in to own account. I assume it is my ajax.js mistake. What do you think? @Rasclatt

Comment: Yes you need to fix the success of the Ajax to accommodate the true or false return from the php

Comment: How should i go about it? Do you have an example to that? @Rasclatt

Comment: I will take a look in a bit here

Comment: I've updated my post. Above there's *draft ajax.js* which i try to code to accommodate the true or false return from php. How should i go from here because it's not working @Rasclatt

Comment: Let me see if I can write something really quickly. It will unfortunately be in jQuery ajax because I don't know how to do regular javascript

Comment: alright sure. it's okay anything will do. i will take a look at how you implement it later @Rasclatt

Comment: Ok I guess it wasn't fast, but I did it. I had to fiddle to get it right. See my EDIT

Comment: You'll want to remove the session stuff from the return. I just put that there so you can see the return in the console.

Comment: trying out. your calling page is normal php file? or javascript? @Rasclatt

Comment: Sorry, I had it actually on my page, you can put it in a .js file as long as you include the jQuery library in your header

Comment: sadly nope i didn't get it working. was thinking if there's another way @Rasclatt

Comment: Hm. Well without seeing it in action on your site I can' be anymore help I'm afraid.

Comment: it's alright. I'll keep trying. Just one thing i quite unsure. You mentioned above that 'you need to base your action on the username (however that is set).' I'm not sure for mine. when user log in it is based on email address and password. Does it mean i base on emailaddr ? @Rasclatt

Comment: Well, sort of. You use an email address as a username, I use whatever, but the session key that you use to assign that value to is what I am referring to. For me is `username` as in `$_SESSION['username']`and it doesn't get set unless the user is logged in. That's how my program knows that a user is authenticated. You may be using `isLoggedIn` as in the case  of -> `$_SESSION["isLoggedIn"]`, which I would not set because you are not logged in unless a username is set. That is where you have to adapt my script to your session scenario.

Comment: thankyou that was a much clearer explanation! However, i included the jQuery and `include_once('includes/firstSession.php');
include_once('includes/myfunctions.php');
process_timeout();` to my **header.php** but ended up giving me blank white screen..

Comment: If you get a blank white screen, then at the very top of your page, even before the `session_start()`, write: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors",1);` that will show you what is wrong. Let me know what that says, I may be able to help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94562/discussion-between-sitinuraini-yakob-and-rasclatt).

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33431916/identify-user-login-session-timeout-updated-post) @Rasclatt